# Kivy Window unable to load

Tags: windows-10, python3, pycharm

I have been trying to use Kivy for a while now but no matter how many strategies I use I keep getting the error message:

```
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I'm using pycharm with python 3.6 so I don't know if that affects anything, but I've tried every solution I can find on stack so far like uninstalling and reinstalling everything from kivy + dependencies to pycharm and python itself... Please help!

full error message attached below:

```
C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe C:/Users/Brian/PycharmProjects/kivy/hi.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Brian\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-01-22_21.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider.
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
  File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 26, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to create virtual environment 
 go to console and type following command 
    codekivy_venv\Scripts\activate